# how to run my kivy windows app on android device

Tags: android, windows, kivy

I've used kivy on windows and developed an app and tried install it through bluestacks on windows android but it said failed to install

what to do to install my app on android so that I can run it on android and use it

Answer (score 5):

You need to give more information than 'it said failed to install'. How did you create your apk? In what way did the install fail?

Without more information, the generic answer is to check the [kivy doc page](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html) about building for android. If you're constrained to windows, you can use the virtual machine mentioned there, or try the [android.kivy.org](http://android.kivy.org/) online build tool.

Answer (score 1):

Trust me @user3395860 it is easier to build a Kivy/Android application on Linux than on Windows.If you cannot afford a machine with Linux as the only operating system, try to set a virtual machine like @inclement suggested (i guess it runs on virtualbox) or do what i did:

I installed vmware on my Windows 7 and downloaded a Ubuntu virtual machine(extention is .vmx) that is compatible with my vmware version and ran it. Next you need to install Kivy on the Ubuntu virtual machine and note that Python is already installed on Linux so you don't need to do so.
to install Kivy on Ubuntu i do the following :

1. Open the terminal : Ctrl + Alt + t
2. Install the kivy PPA : `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy` (you will be prompted for your admin password here)
3. Update your system : `$ sudo apt-get update`
4. install kivy : `$ sudo apt-get install python-kivy`
5. test if Kivy is installed : open terminal as in 1 , type python to open the python interpreter in the terminal then type `>>> import kivy.`

to build your Android application after you have copied it to the virtual machine and tested it go to : [this](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html) . It is very useful and detailed.

Comment: The provided VM is already set up to build APKs using Kivy and python-for-android. I wouldn't bother with setting up the environment manually unless you're running Linux. +1 anyway though :)

Comment: yes @RyanP it is so true, but it is a real nice experience (but lengthy) to build the APK yourself. I love Linux that's my problem... many thanks :)

Comment: Kind of a sad story that a different OS is needed to just build the application to android.